# PHP stored procedure not working

Tags: php, stored-procedures

I have about 10 stored procedures and they are all working fine but when i call this specific one with the php the insert to the database does not work. When i execute it in phpmyadmin it does work so the problem lies in the php.

PHP file

```
<?php

 include 'test.php';

 session_start();

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $recipeTitle = $_POST['title'];
    $recipeDescription = $_POST['description'];
    $recipePic = $_POST['picture'];
    $categoryId = $_POST['catId'];
    $subCatId = $_POST['subId'];
    $prepTime = $_POST['prepTime'];
    $cookingTime = $_POST['cookTime'];
    $cookingTemperature = $_POST['temp'];
    $degrees = $_POST['degrees'];

    $conn->query("CALL RB_AddNewRecipe('$recipeTitle', '$recipeDescription', 
    '$recipePic', $categoryId, $subCatId, $prepTime, 
                $cookingTime, $cookingTemperature, '$degrees')");

    header('Location: ../allRecipes.php');
    end;

     }

    ?>
```

Procedure

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO RECIPE
(title, description, image, category_id, sub_category_id, preparation_time,  
cooking_time, temperature, degrees)
VALUES(p_title, p_description, p_image, p_category_id, p_sub_category_id, 
p_preparation_time, p_cooking_time, p_temperature, p_degrees);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS recipe_id;

END
```

Comment: what type of database connection are you using (PDO, mysqli), is there any error displayed?

Comment: There is no error displayed and i have done about ten other procedures like this and they all are working.

Comment: include 'test.php';

session_start();

$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

// If user clicks the yes button end session, delete account and redirect to sign up page
$conn->query("CALL RB_DeleteMember($id)");
session_destroy();
header('Location: ../signupPage.php');
end;

Comment: Is an example of a working one.

Comment: are you using mysqli to connecto to the database? if so after the `$conn->query("CALL CODE")` write the following `or die($conn->error);` and let us know if any error appears

Comment: Yes i connect with mysqli and i put in that line and it returned this error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , '')' at line 1

Comment: try to use instead of `$conn->query()` -> `$conn->multi_query()` . It seems that in other procedures you do not try to return any result, but on this one you want to fetch the recipe_id. So you execute the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` query

Comment: So i run two querys?

Comment: Yes i left everything the same just change query to multi_query.

Comment: also i would suggest you to escape your inputs do not use raw $_POST variables. take a look about the http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php **real_escape_string** function , it may be that you try to pass **'** (single quote) character and it breaks your query. You will have to secure the user inputs from XSS attacks too by escaping the html entities too.

Comment: I will take a look now.

Comment: Still it does not insert, have it working with mysqli_query tho

Comment: tried to recreate the error based on the information you gave, but without luck. The procedure runs normally even with the usage of query. So you must give us more information. Post your table structure, show us your form, tell us what data you enter, the version of php,mysql etc.

Comment: It is definitely strange so probably a small error i made. I will just leave it run with mysqli_query, thanks for your help.